# How to shuffle contents of string array

Tags: vba

The following code creates an array that is filled with either of the two strings: "A" or "B" based on probability. I wish to randomly shuffle the order of the array before pasting it back to the worksheet.

```
Sub CreateData()

Dim arr(1 To 1000) As String

For i = 1 To 1000

    If Rnd <= 0.4 Then
        arr(i) = "A"
    Else
        arr(i) = "B"
    End If
        
Next i

arTesting = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
Range("A1:A100").Value = arTesting

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you want to 'shuffle' the array?

Comment: @norie re-order the elements in the array in random order

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShuffleArray.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateData()
Dim arr(1 To 1000, 1 To 1) As String
Dim arrShuffled(1 To 1000, 1 To 1) As String
Dim Moved As Boolean
Dim cnt As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim rw As Long

    For I = 1 To 1000

        If Rnd <= 0.4 Then
            arr(I, 1) = "A"
        Else
            arr(I, 1) = "B"
        End If

    Next I

    Do
        Moved = False
        Do
            rw = Application.RandBetween(1, 1000)
            If arrShuffled(rw, 1) = "" Then
                cnt = cnt + 1
                arrShuffled(rw, 1) = arr(cnt, 1)
                Moved = True
            End If
        Loop Until Moved
    Loop Until cnt = 1000
    
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1000").Value = arrShuffled

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use another one array and gradually fill it with data from the main array (`arr`) with the help of `RandBetween` worksheet function.

Note: I don't have access to Excel at the moment, so cannot check the code, but I hope that you got the idea.

```
Dim n As Integer
Dim arrShuffled(1 To 1000) As String
n = 1 ' current position to be filled in new array
Do While n <= 1000
    i = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 1000)
    If arr(i) <> "" Then
        arrShuffled(n) = arr(i)
        arr(i) = "" ' clear data in order not use it twice
        n = n + 1
    End If
Loop
```